# Accessing an object on 2 threads at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an c# application which owns 2 threads. One thread is creating an object while the same object is being used in the second thread. Most of the time it works fine but some time it gives and error `Object is in use currently elsewhere.`

How to make it possible for threads to use object at same time?

Thanks

**Edit**

I am accessing a `Bitmap` object. One thread is creating this bitmap from a stream, displaying it on `PictureBox` and the second thread is again converting this `Bitmap` to `Byte` and transmitting it on the network.

Comment: Add some code and tell us what Type the object is.

Comment: "Object is in use currently elsewhere." doesn't sound like a standard .NET exception - what exactly are you doing here? any particular libraries? Note that objects need to be carefully written to be thread-safe; it isn't clear whether your objects *are* thread-safe, or are simply being tortured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic approach would be a locking object (in a 1-1 relation with the shared object) and a `lock` statement:

```
MyObject shared = ...;
object locker = new object();

// thread A
lock(locker)
{
  // use 'shared'
}

// thread B
lock(locker)
{
  // use 'shared'
}
```

#### After the Edit

If you are converting the Bitmap in any way it is probably better to forget about Parallel. It is a complicated class with its own internal locking.

If you don't convert, then don't use the bitmap. It will be easier (not trivial) to fork the incoming stream for PictureBox and outgoing stream.

Answer (score 2):

The language of the error message makes it sound like it's coming from the GDI subsystem or something similar. Is this a GUI application? If yes, the most likely cause is that you are accessing GUI elements from a "non GUI" thread. For the uninitiated, all operations on any GUI control, like a form or button must be sent to it through it's message pump. You can do that by roughly doing

```
if (form.InvokeRequired)
{
    form.BeginInvoke( your operation method);
} 
else
{ 
    (same operation method);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am accessing a Bitmap object. One thread is creating this bitmap from a stream, displaying it on PictureBox and the second thread is again converting this Bitmap to Byte and transmitting it on the network

Accessing `Bitmap` object from several thread would not cause `InvalidOperationException`. It could break your your data if you write and read the same instance concurrently, but as far as I can tell `Bitmap` does not impose a specific threading model. On the other hand a `PictureBox` does, so I suspect you are trying to either read or write back to `PictureBox` instance from a non-GUI worker thread.

Comment: Yes! I am accessing the `PictureBox` to send the bitmap.

Comment: Well, this you cannot do. Use some of the default Async-Patterns to avoid this. Some keywords to look for: `SynchronizationContext`, `APM`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `lock` this variable each time it is used by either one of the threads.

As such:

```
object mylock;

lock(mylock)
{
//do someething with object
}//lock scope finishes here
```

where `mylock` is used by each lock that accesses this particular variable.

Comment: pedant: you don't lock against a *variable*; you lock against an *object*, typically stored in a *field*. But until we see more context, it is not obvious to me that this is the right approach...